# How to represent an array with empty elements in JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sparse-matrix

I have an array in JavaScript that looks like this:

```
var pattern = [ ["C5", 3], , , , , , , , ["C5", 3], , , ]
```

I want to store it in a json file like this:

```
{
  "pattern": [
               ["C5", 3], , , , , , , , ["C5", 3], , ,
             ]
}
```

JSONLint tells me this:

```
Parse error on line 6:
...        ],        ,        ,        
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

So I understand I can't let the space between commas empty. What's similar to empty, but is accepted by JSON standards?

This pattern file is part of a Javascript Music Tracker I'm making that's similar to impulse tracker, and I want the json file to be as clean as possible.

Comment: `null` is the "empty" value in JSON.

Comment: fill empty places with `''` empty string

Comment: Empty string looks like a nice approach. Will try.

Comment: fill empty places with `0` number. That will take one character instead of 2 for empty string. `0 == null == ''`

Comment: I ended using `[]` at the time for simplicity. It worked and I haven't touched since... https://github.com/ericoporto/fangamk/tree/master/GameMusic

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have empty space in JSON, you should fill it with `null`.

Example:

```
var pattern = [ ["C5", 3], null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ["C5", 3], null, null, null, null, ...... ]
```

Comment: I don't get why my question is getting downvoted to hell but I understand your answer. I knew `null` but I was wondering if there was something cleaner - 4 characters can add a lot in bigger songs with multiple channels. Thanks, will think about it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `null` with a **sparse array**, you could use the object representation of an array.

```
 pattern = [["C5", 3], , , , , , , , ["C5", 3], , , ]
```

... would be replaced by an object with index value as properties and an additional `length` property:

```
parse_array = {
    0: ["C5", 3],
    8: ["C5", 3],
    length: 12
}
```

This object can be generated from the array using its `reduce` method:

```
parse_array = pattern.reduce( ( obj, val, i ) =>
  {
    obj.length++
    if ( val )
      obj[i] = val
    return obj
  }, { length: 0 } )
```

Then it's easy to convert the object into a JavaScript Array, using a simple *arrow function*:

```
pattern = Array.from( parse_array, v => v )
```

```js
//Encode array

var pattern = [["C5",3],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,["C5",3],null,null,null]

out.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( pattern ) + "\n"

var parse1 = pattern.reduce( ( obj, val, i ) =>
  {
    obj.length++
    if ( val )
      obj[i] = val
    return obj
  }, { length } )

out.innerHTML += JSON.stringify( parse1 ) + "\n"


//Decode object

var parse2 = {
  0: ["C5", 3],
  8: ["C5", 3],
  length: 12
}

out.innerHTML += JSON.stringify( parse2 ) + "\n"

out.innerHTML += JSON.stringify( Array.from( parse2,  v => v ) )  + "\n"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>JSON array with empty items</h3>
 <pre id="out"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```