# Push an empty element into javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I push empty element to an existing Js array, lets assume :

```js
var arr = [54,77,21];
var target = [54,77,21,,,,36];
arr.push(); //do not append an empty element into the array.
arr.push();

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); //output: [54,77,21]
```

How to append empty elements so "arr" will be equivalent to "target" array?

Comment: Nope I tried that it will append a string element [54,77,21,""]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to represent an array with empty elements in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585552/how-to-represent-an-array-with-empty-elements-in-json)

Comment: What you try to do? Why you need these empty elements? Maybe you need object for that: `{0:54, 1: 77, 2: 21, 6: 36}`?

Comment: @Justinas I have a chartjs and it require the array like this , so it will not render a point in there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could address the index directly. This builds a sparse array.

```js
var arr = [54,77,21];

arr[6] = 36;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Or push `undefined` until you like to push the value. This returns a filled array.

```js
var arr = [54,77,21];

arr.push(undefined);
arr.push(undefined);
arr.push(undefined);
arr.push(36);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

By using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), you get for undefined or sparse items `null`, because [JSON](https://json.org/) knows only `null` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: yes, i mentioned this. with stringifgy, you get `undefined` for sparse elements. later with parsing there is no difference.

Comment: JSON.stringify was confusing because it changes the empty element into null

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

```
arr.length++;
```

> You can set the length property to truncate an array at any time. **When you extend an array by changing its length property, the number of actual elements increases**; for example, if you set length to 3 when it is currently 2, the array now contains 3 elements, which causes the third element to be a non-iterable empty slot.

But note that JSON does not support sparse arrays. I.e. you cannot see empty slots with `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var arr = [54,77,21];
arr.length++;
arr.length++;
arr.length++;
arr.push(36);
console.log(arr);
```

(FYI: Stack Snippets do not seem to support sparse arrays correctly. You need to run that code in the browser console instead.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method.

```js
    var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    var arrtarget = [1, 2, 3, 4, , , , 5, 6];

    console.log(arr1);
    console.log(arrtarget);

    newArr = arr1.concat([, , , 5,6]);

    console.log(newArr);
```

Alternatively, you could use the [Array.Prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method as

```
arr1.push(undefined);
```